# How to upgrade multiple Macs to OS X 10.10.4?

Tags: macos, upgrade

I own multiple Macs at home and, when I installed Yosemite (10.10) I downloaded the installer from the App Store on the main computer, then copied "/Applications/Install\ OS\ X\ Yosemite" to a safe location, and used the copy to upgrade the other computers skipping the long download time.

Now that the upgrade to 10.10.4 is available, I noticed that there is no "Install" executable in /Applications - so I had to repeat the long download for all my three computers.  How could I use a single download for all computers again?

Answer (score 9):

For every OS X 'delta' release  - 10.10.1/2/3/ ...10.10.4 etc - which App Store will download to each Mac there is a simultaneous 'combo' update release which rolls up all the previous deltas into one single downloadable update.
It was for many years considered the 'pro' way to do the update, as it can also correct potential update issues that the delta can't.

You can always find updates related to OS X [here](http://support.apple.com/downloads/macos).

As the combo update doesn't use the App Store "download, install, delete" structure, you can pass it from machine to machine at your leisure.

Maybe not as slick as using the server - but it's free ;-)

From comments -
The combo update can also be applied to machines which are already running the current version of the OS, unlike the App Store's delta "update" mechanism. This can sometimes correct issues that may linger after doing a series of incremental [delta] updates.
The combo updater is invariably larger than the incremental updates; but it is worth it, just for the peace of mind.

Comment: The combo update can also be applied to machines which are already running the current version of the OS, unlike the App Store's "update" mechanism.  As @Tetsujin mentioned, this can sometimes "correct" issues that may linger after doing a series of incremental updates.  The combo updater is invariably larger than the incremental updates; but it is worth it, just for the peace of mind.  ;-)

Comment: Good point, @Kent - I ought to roll that into the answer.

Comment: Thank you; I think this will be the way I will follow for future updates.

Answer (score 3):

The OS X Server App allows you to cache data on your network as well as manage multiple devices and installations/updates on them. This would simplify things for you in the long run, but there might be a slight learning curve to start out. I haven't used the Yosemite version of the Server App yet so can't give you more specifics. It's something to look into anyway to streamline your process.

Comment: I had a look to the OS X server app on the app store; I didn't understand, however, if it has to be installed on the main machine only or on all pf them.  I don't care too much, I will follow the other ('combo') way...